# Date Format Spring in milliseconds when it was previously in format : yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, datetime, jackson

I have built my application to Sprint version 2.7.7. Now, when a date is returned by a Controller method, we receive it as a TimeStamp in milliseconds.

For example this method:

```
@PostMapping("stbClobil")
public Date getClobil(
        @RequestParam(name = "idBilan") Integer idBilan, 
        @RequestParam(name = "idDomaine") Integer idDomaine) {
    System.out.println( this.stbService.getMaxClobil(idBalance, idDomain));
    return this.stbService.getMaxClobil(idBalance, idDomain);
}
```

Instead of returning this date: `2022-01-30T23:00:00.000+00:00`, it returns this: `1675119600000`.

However, when returning a JSON object with a date attribute, the date is in the correct format.

I tried to use the `@JsonFormat`, without success.
I also tried to change in the properties like this:
`spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false`
And also, I tried to change the properties of `spring.mvc.date`, `spring.mvc.date-time`, `spring.mvc.time`, without success too.

Comment: Sorry, this does not make sense. A `Date` neither prints like `2022-01-30T23:00:00.000+00:00` nor like `1675119600000`. Typically like `Mon Jan 31 00:00:00 CET 2022`, though the subclasses of `Date` look different. Also the two results are equal (they denote the same point in time), so you are getting the value that you asked for. What makes you think that t is not right? And how did you obtain the formats you mention? A [mre], please?

Comment: Not answering your question, you should not use the `Date` class at all. It was poorly designed and is long outdated. Use `Instant` (or another appropriate class) from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: I am assuming that your Date is a java.util.Date. I tested with spring-boot 2.7.7 (jdk11) and 3.0.4 (jdk17) and it always returns it formatted as follows: "2023-03-17T13:32:52.644+00:00". I need some more code to determine the actual class of Date.